# How can I stop publishing only the video track/audio track using agora web sdk ng?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

```js
async toggleVideoCam() {

    if (this.rtc.localVideoTrack) {
      await this.rtc.client.localVideoTrack.setEnabled(false);
      this.rtc.localVideoTrack.close();
      document.getElementById('localvideo').remove();
    } else {
      await this.rtc.client.localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
    
      const playerContainer = document.createElement('div');
      const userIdContainer = document.createElement('span');
      userIdContainer.className = 'user-id-holder';
      playerContainer.className = 'localUserVideo';
      let liveStreamContainer = document.querySelector('.videoTracks-container');

      playerContainer.id = 'localvideo';
      userIdContainer.innerHTML = 'local video';
      playerContainer.append(userIdContainer);

      if (!document.getElementById(playerContainer.id)) {
        liveStreamContainer.append(playerContainer);
        // Play the local audio and video tracks
        // SDK dynamically creates a player in the container for playing the local video track
        this.rtc.localVideoTrack.play(playerContainer);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I want to toggle publishing `localVideoTrack` how can I do that?
Yes, I have added a setEnabled method on localVideoTrack and I got cannot read a property setEnabled of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply invoke the `setEnabled` method on the local track with an appropriate boolean value to toggle publishing the track. https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/ilocalvideotrack.html#setenabled

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEnabled' of undefined

Comment: Can you please update your code(in the question) with setEnabled?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you have to use await with setenabled method and second is tracks are not present in client object.

```
  try {
              if (this.rtc.localVideoTrack) await rtc.localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);  // This is used to publish camera
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, 'error');
          }
        }
        else {
          try {
            if (this.rtc.localVideoTrack) await rtc.localVideoTrack.setEnabled(false); // With this you can close camera
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, 'error');
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use last one for audio and first for video:

```
this.rtc.localVideoTrack.setEnabled(boolean)
```

```
this.rtc.localAudioTrack.setEnabled(boolean)
```